# Getting facebook likes

Tags: facebook, get-request, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

With Graph Api I can get Facebook Pages likes(/likes). I need get all liked/favorite photos, statuses, comments, posts... I cant find requests for these.

Is it possibly get the data?

Comment: What did you try so far? You can't expect to get an answer, if you don't show any effort in solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be able to execute an [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) on the [`like` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/). Something like this:

```
SELECT object_id, object_type FROM like WHERE user_id =504135887
```

This will return data similar to this:

```
{
      "object_id": "xxx", 
      "object_type": "post", 
      "post_id": ""
    }, 
    {
      "object_id": "aaa", 
      "object_type": "photo", 
      "post_id": ""
    }, 
    {
      "object_id": "bbb", 
      "object_type": "life event", 
      "post_id": ""
    }, 
    {
      "object_id": "ccc", 
      "object_type": "status", 
      "post_id": ""
    }, 
    ...
}
```

As you can see, you are able to extract the `object_id` and also the type of object. From this result you'll be able to see all of the users "likes" on objects. To get information on the actual `object_id` you have extracted, you can just perform a regular request (with the appropriate access token) to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2/OBJECT_ID`.

Comment: Need to try. But FQL will not be available in the next version of the API.